# can it possible to built facebook login functionality in extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to include facebook login functionality in my chrome extension. I have included

> connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js   file in popup.html. But not working.

i m using code

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId: 'APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
            //channelUrl : '//www.example.com/', // Channel File for x-domain communication
            status: true, // check the login status upon init?
            cookie: true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
            xfbml: true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

        // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
        console.log(FB);

    };

    // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
    (function(d, debug) {
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {
            return;
        }
        js = d.createElement('script');
        js.id = id;
        js.async = true;
        js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
        ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
    }(document, /*debug*/false));
```

but getting error

Refused to load the script 'http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' chrome-extension-resource:".

Comment: What does "But not working" mean? What do Chrome Developer Tools tell you?

Comment: Ok Now i have edit my question with complete detail. Please refer it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following code and it works, without damaging the CSP

```
    function loginfacebook()
    {       
        chrome.windows.create(
        {
            'url': "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=yourclientid&redirect_uri=https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&scope=email&response_type=token"
        }, null);

        chrome.tabs.query({active:true}, function(tabs){
            tabid = tabs[0].id;
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabid, tab)
            {
                var cadena = tab.url;
                if (cadena != null)
                {
                    var resultado = cadena.match(/[\\?&#]access_token=([^&#])*/i);
                }
                if (resultado != null)
                {                                           

                    token = resultado[0];
                    token = token.substring(14);
                    storagetoken(token);
                };
            });
```

Comment: i have used it and work properly. From this code i got the access token and using it i have parsed it , get email in backend and logged in successfully. But i want to be my popup remained open as when i complete login i can change my popup html by ajax.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message says, the Facebook script isn't [CSP-compliant](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). I haven't looked at that script, but if you can't modify it and fix the CSP issues, you have a couple options in general for dealing with such scripts:

1. Put it in a [sandboxed iframe](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/security/sandboxed-iframes/).
2. Put the script in a [<webview>](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/apps/webview_tag.html).

Unfortunately, the point of that Facebook script is likely to set a cookie after FB authentication, and that cookie would stay in either the iframe or the webview, so neither of these approaches will end up with the required cookie in your main app. You'll have to figure out a way to transmit the product (cookie) of the FB login operation to your app, likely through postMessage. If you do that legwork and succeed, please post your results somewhere, such as in a sample app on GitHub.